# Implement KVM Console Log in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing KVM console log, but the API never returns any data. 
This my sample code implemented. Please let me know if you found any doubt.

```
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Account;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.logging.Syslog;
import com.softlayer.api.service.user.Customer;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;

    private void kvmConsoleLogs() {

        Guest.Service gService = Guest.service(client, 21138311L);
        List<Syslog> conList = gService.getConsoleAccessLog();

        for (Syslog syslog : conList) {

            System.out.println(" port : " + syslog.getSourcePort());
            System.out.println(" message : " + syslog.getMessage());
            System.out.println(" event type : " + syslog.getEventType());

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for some reason you need to set resultLimits when you call the getConsoleAccessLog method

try using REST to verify that:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$VIRTUALGUESTID/getConsoleAccessLog?resultLimit=0,25
```

So in JAva set the resultLimit like this:

```
gService.setResultLimit(new ResultLimit(25));
```

and try again.

For more inforamtion about resultLimit in the Java client see the pagination section here:

https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-java

Regards